# Using LiDAR to identify coniferous and deciduous trees

Tags: lidar, classification, vegetation-index, forest-ecology

Is it possible to use only LiDAR data to distinguish between mostly coniferous and deciduous forest? I have a LiDAR data from spring and summer, but they have different point spacing.

Comment: There is some research about intensity values, but I don't think it is applicable to larger datasets. I could not find anything about a specific workflow that can be used. Satellite imagery would probably be better, but I am using LiDAR, and maybe imagery and LiDAR can be used to compliment each other. I have data over the same area, but they are 2 years apart.

Comment: There are multiple workflows. For example starting with [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/FUSION/fusion_overview.html), or [lidR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf) to generate different lidar metrics. Maybe the ratio of points hitting the ground compared to the canopy can be used. I have not tried it. You have sample plots with the truth to compare with?

Comment: I agree with @BERA, LiDAR can be used for classification purposes. The general workflow is to produce a variety of grid metrics and use training data to train a model such as Random Forests to make predictions based on your training data. Differentiating conifer from deciduous would be easily accomplished using LiDAR data. Here is a paper where the authors used this approach to map fuel metrics from LiDAR: https://www.mdpi.com/2571-6255/2/3/38.

Comment: "Deep learning for conifer/deciduous classification of airborne LiDAR 3D point clouds representing individual trees" [2018] PDF available > https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08872

Comment: Are you after a pixel-based, wall-to-wall, predictive approach or an individual tree segmentation approach?

Comment: There are tons of publications describing methods with pretty good accuracies. So the anwser is *yes*. But I guess you were expecting a software doing it. Sadly publication almost never come in a reproducible way. As far as I know there is no ready-to-use tool to perform such task. You can only try to reproduce former studies.